# I cannot start rabbitmq on my mac

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have brew installed rabbitmq on my mac and have tried the following

```
rabbitmq-server start

sbin/service rabbitmq-server start
```

and neither work.How do I start it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should be able to run `/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmq-server` or use `brew services start rabbitmq`

Comment: That worked. I saw this no where in the docs. How'd you know this?

Comment: @losee, You can use `brew services start[stop/restart/list]` for run RabbitMQ service in the background (or mysql, redis...). Homebrew installs packages in  `/usr/local/Cellar/` and then symlinks their files into `/usr/local/`

Answer (score 13):

Here are a few commands to get you started. Just open your cli and type from anywhere

```
brew services start rabbitmq     //start 
brew services stop  rabbitmq     //stop

brew services restart rabbitmq   //restart
```

You can also list all the running services by

```
brew services list
```

#### Alternative way -

Go to the directory where `rabbitMQ` is installed and run following commands

```
cd rabbitmq_server-3.5.3/      //check you's version 
sbin/rabbitmq-server           //start server 

sbin/rabbitmqctl shutdown      //stop server
```

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATED**

USL: http://localhost:15672/

Login try this

```
username: guest
password: guest
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `brew services start rabbitmq` in terminal after that go to

**localhost:15672** enter username and password which is

```
username-guest 
password-guest
```